# Produce daily forecasts from monthly averages using Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have daily data going back years. If I firstly wanted to see what the monthly average of these was, then to project out this monthly average forecast for the next few years I have written the following code.

For example, my forecast for the next few January's will be the average of the last few January's, and the same for Feb, Mar etc. Over the past few years my January number is 51.8111, so for the January's in my forecast period I want every day in every January to be this 51.8111 number (i.e. moving the monthly to daily granularity).

My question is, my code seems a bit long winded and with the loop, could potentially be a little slow?  For my own learning I was wondering, what is a better way of taking daily data, averaging it by a time period, then projecting out this time period? I was looking at map and apply functions within Pandas, but couldn't quite work it out.

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)

# create random dataframe of daily values
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=100,size=2317), 
                  columns=['value'], 
                  index=pd.date_range(start='2014-01-01', end=dt.date.today()-dt.timedelta(days=1), freq='D'))

# gain average by month over entire date range
df_by_month = df.groupby(df.index.month).mean()

# create new dataframe with date range for forecast
df_forecast = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start=dt.date.today(), periods=1095, freq='D'))
df_forecast['value'] = 0

# project forward the monthly average to each day
for val in df_forecast.index:
    df_forecast.loc[val]['value'] = df_by_month.loc[val.month]

# create new dataframe joining together the historical value and forecast
df_complete = df.append(df_forecast)
```

Comment: Please share a sample dataframe input with expected output for better understanding.

Comment: The example is there. I am happy with the output, I am asking whether there is a better way to get the same output by using a clever method, such as map or apply rather than the simple loop I used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`Index.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html) by months by column `value` from `df_by_month`:

```
# create new dataframe with date range for forecast
df_forecast = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start=dt.date.today(), periods=1095, freq='D'))
df_forecast['value'] = df_forecast.index.month.map(df_by_month['value'])
```